# Get current system time?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Whats the best way to get the current time (HH:MM:SS) using Objective-C. I would guess I should be looking at NSDate & NSDateFormatter. I had a quick glance at the docs and it looked a little more convoluted than I expected, so I thought I would check here to make sure I was on the right track.

gary

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outputFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *newDateString = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:now];
NSLog(@"newDateString %@", newDateString);
[outputFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 6):

You are, in fact, on the right track. Use

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
```

to get the current date and time. Use `NSDateFormatter` to format it. See [this link](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) for a how-to on date and time formatting.

For your situation, you could do this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"%H:%M:%S"];
NSString *timeString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Answer (score 5):

```
NSDateFormatter *DateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];  
NSLog(@"%@",[DateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```