# Display a different background image at certain times of the day (iOS)

Tags: time, background, objective-c-2.0

For my app, I want to display a different image and text for different times of day. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current time:

[Get current system time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313263/get-current-system-time)

Then use an if statement with the times that your program should change background.

You can refer to [set background image for entire iPhone / iPad app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915474/set-background-image-for-entire-iphone-ipad-app) for how to change the background.

Comment: How would NSDate work with an if statement? Also, I want different times, not dates.

Comment: Same way actually. First you should create the NSDate object and then use it in the if statement as a datestring

Comment: Can you actually tell me how to do this? I can't figure this out by going to various answers and trying to piece it together. I tried to use an if else if statement, but I get the error: conversion of int to NSString disallowed with ARC. Any ideas?